# Namespace for Exception class is not specified Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error-log

I show this error in marketplace review

> Namespace for Exception class is not specified.

Here is my code:

```
public function uploadFile($scope)
{   
   try {
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $scope]);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);

        if ($uploader->save($this->getBaseDir())) {
            return $uploader->getUploadedFileName();    
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new $e('The file was not uploaded.', $code);
    }
    return '';
}
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 6):

Replace `Exception $e` to `\Exception $e`

**Final Code**

```
public function uploadFile($scope)
{   
   try {
        $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $scope]);
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);

        if ($uploader->save($this->getBaseDir())) {
            return $uploader->getUploadedFileName();    
        }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new $e('The file was not uploaded.', $code);
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: Use of die language construct is discouraged. I am using header location in phtml, so using die